# Reduction from Atm to A (of my choice) , and from A to Atm

Tags: algorithm, computation-theory, turing-machines, reduction

Reduction of many one , is not symmetric . I'm trying to prove it but it doesn't work 
so well .

Given two languages A and B ,where A is defined as

```
A={w| |w| is even} , i.e. `w` has an even length
```

and `B=A_TM` , where A_TM is undecidable but Turing-recognizable!

Given the following Reduction:

```
f(w) = { (P(x):{accept;}),epsilon    , if |w| is even
f(w) = { (P(x):{reject;}),epsilon    , else
```

(Please forgive me for not using Latex , I have no experience with it)

As I can see, a reduction from A <= B (from A to A_TM) is possible , and works great.
However , I don't understand why B <= A , is not possible .

Can you please clarify and explain ?

Thanks 
Ron

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume for a moment that `B <= A`. Then there is a function `f:Sigma*->Sigma*` such that:

```
f(w) = x in A           if w is in B
     = x not in A       if w is not in B
```

Therefore, we can describe the following algorithm [turing machine] `M` on input `w`:

```
1. w' <- f(w)
2. if |w'| is even return true
3. return false
```

It is easy to prove that `M` accepts `w` if and only if `w` is in `B` [left as an exercise to the reader], thus `L(M) = B`.

 Also, `M` stops for any input `w` [from its construction]. Thus - L(M) is decideable.

But we got that `L(M) = B` is decideable - and that is a contradiction, because `B = A_TM` is undecideable!